# Java stream: merge map keys by function

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a map `Map<String, List<String>>`. I'd like to merge keys, if one key is a function of another, for example:

if the function is "prefix", I'd like given these values in the map:

```
{"123", ["a"]]}
{"85", ["a","b"]]}
{"8591", ["c"]}
```

to get a new map with these values:

```
{"123", ["a"]}
{"85", ["a","b","c"]}
```

This map "reduction" is called as part of a user request, so it must be fast. I know I can do `O(n^2)` but I'm looking for something better, parallel if possible.

Below is a code that find the super key for each key by calling the `getMatchingKey` function:

```
    Map<String, Set<String>> result= new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : input.entrySet()){
        String x = getMatchingKey(entry.getKey(), input.keySet());
        if (!resultt.containsKey(x)){
            resultt.put(x, new HashSet<String>());
        }
        resultt.get(x).addAll((input.get(x)));
        resultt.get(x).addAll((entry.getValue()));
    }
```

**EDIT**

The full problem I'm having is such:
Given a map of entities names to their footprint `Map<String, Footprint>` I would like to remove `Subnet` from `Footprint` which is included in a different entity.

`Footprint` object include a List of `Subent`.

So my though was to reverse the map to be a `Map<Subnet, List<String>>` mapping all subnets to their entities names, than union all subnets and at the end filter the subnets from the original Map. Something like this:

```
    public Map<String, Footprint> clearOverlaps(Map<String, Footprint> footprintsMap) {

    Map<Subnet, List<String>> subnetsToGroupNameMap =
            footprintsMap.entrySet()
                    .parallelStream()
                    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().getSubnets().stream().map(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(i, e.getKey())))
                    .collect(groupingBy(e->e.getKey(), mapping(e->e.getValue(), toList())));

    Map<Subnet, Set<String>> subnetsToGroupNameFiltered = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Subnet, List<String>> entry : subnetsToGroupNameMap.entrySet()){
        Subnet x = findSubnetBiggerOrEqualToMe(entry.getKey(), subnetsToGroupNameMap.keySet());

        if (!subnetsToGroupNameFiltered .containsKey(x)){
            subnetsToGroupNameFiltered .put(x, new HashSet<String>());
        }
        subnetsToGroupNameFiltered .get(x).addAll((subnetsToGroupNameMap.get(x)));
        subnetsToGroupNameFiltered .get(x).addAll((entry.getValue()));

    }
    footprintsMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry->entry.getValue().getSubnets().stream().filter(x->!subnetsToGroupNameFiltered .containsKey(x)));
    return footprintsMap;
}
```

The function `findSubnetBiggerOrEqualToMe` finds in all the subnets the biggest one that include Subnet instance.

But since this function should run on user request, and the Map contains tens of entities with tens of thousands of subnets, I need something that will be fast (memory is free:))

Comment: ppl here on SO usually want to see some effort made before helping out. What did you try?

Comment: If you have an O(n²) version, perhaps you should post that for a start. Someone might see a way to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here is a working example which I would like to improve:

Comment: Is this really about streams, or are you looking for a way to make this faster than O(n²)? Because just using streams won't make it faster. But if keys are considered equal if they are a prefix of each other, you can make is _substantially_ faster by using a [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of comparing each pair. So, what does `getMatchingKey` do?

Comment: @tobias_k you're right - this is not a stream question, I just assumed It can be done faster using streams. I know about prefix trees, but this is not the case here as I simplified and reduced the real problem to something easier to explain than the real problem I have. Will edit the question to include the entire problem, maybe my original thoughts led me the wrong way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with an approach that first sorts the subnets lexicographically. This would reduce the overhead caused by your call to `findSubnetBiggerOrEqualToMe` from n^2 to the sort algorithms complexity (usually ~nlog(n)). I will assume that you can order the subnets as the logic should be similar to what you have in `findSubnetBiggerOrEqualToMe`.

Ideally, if all of a subnet's supernets were prefixes of the same set, it would then be a simple reduction in linear time. Example `[1, 2, 22, 222, 3]`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedEntries.size() - 1; i++)
{
    Entry<Subnet, Set<String>> subnet = sortedEntries.get(i);
    Entry<Subnet, Set<String>> potentialSupernet = sortedEntries.get(i + 1);

    if (subnet.getKey().isPrefix(potentialSupernet.getKey()))
    {
        potentialSupernet.getValue().addAll(subnet.getValue());
        sortedEntries.remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

But as soon as you encounter cases like `[1, 2, 22, 23]` (22 and 23 are not prefixes of the same net), it is not a simple reduction anymore, as you have to look further than just the next entry to make sure you find all supernets (2 has to be merged into both 22 **and** 23):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedEntries.size(); i++)
{
    Entry<Subnet, Set<String>> subnet = sortedEntries.get(i);

    for (int j = i + 1; j < sortedEntries.size(); j++)
    {
        Entry<Subnet, Set<String>> nextNet = sortedEntries.get(j);
        if (!subnet.getKey().isPrefix(nextNet.getKey()))
        {
            break;
        }

        Entry<Subnet, Set<String>> nextNextNet = j < sortedEntries.size() - 1 ? sortedEntries.get(j + 1) : null;
        if (nextNextNet == null || !subnet.getKey().isPrefix(nextNextNet.getKey()))
        {
            // biggest, and last superset found
            nextNet.getValue().addAll(subnet.getValue());
            sortedEntries.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
        else if (!nextNet.getKey().isPrefix(nextNextNet.getKey()))
        {
            // biggest superset found, but not last
            nextNet.getValue().addAll(subnet.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

How well this approach reduces n^2 depends on the number of independent nets. The smaller the sets with equal prefix are, the less square the runtime should be.

In the end, I think this approach is very similar in behavior to a prefix tree approach. There, you would build the tree and then iterate the leaves (i.e. the biggest supersets) and merge all their ancestors' items into their sets.